# Programmatically Run Gradle Test Given File and Optional Test Name

Tags: java, gradle, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write a Java application which is a command line tool, where part of it will run a Gradle test in your own application on invoking it. It will have the full path to the file and an optional test name at its disposal. I could shell out and run it manually e.g.:

```java
gradlew <module>:test --tests <fullTestName>
```

but I am looking for a way to use the Gradle API to do so. However, I'm not seeing any packages on Maven to have my cmd line app be able to hook into the current directory's gradle project and be able to call it's test task.

For example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.gradle:gradle-core:6.8.3")
}
```

results in a 'not found' error.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the [Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/third_party_integration.html#embedding)?

Comment: Yes @Slaw I think that's it! I'm now running into an error: "Plugin with id '<plugin name>' not found." Is there some other config I need to set to run?

Comment: I would expect that if running `./gradlew <task>` works, then so will the Tooling API. But I've personally never used the Tooling API.